# Java setLocation() Resets after new keyEvent

Tags: java

By first, sorry for bad English.

I've got a question. I've coded a simple keyEvent thing that let move my JLabel. It works fine, but when i ask my code to change the setText by using keyEvent, he will reset my setLocation(). Here's my code:

```
package view;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import controller.Keylisteners;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Builder extends JFrame {

public JLabel plaatje = new JLabel();
public static Builder instance;

public static Builder getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new Builder();
    }
    return instance;
}

public Builder() {
    setSize(getMaximumSize());
    this.addKeyListener(new Keylisteners());
    setLayout(null);
    //plaatje.setText("UP");
    GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(595, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(plaatje)
                .addGap(567))
    );
    groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(570, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(plaatje, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 65,       GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
    );
    getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);


} 
}
```

And the other class.

```
package controller;

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import view.Builder;

public class Keylisteners extends KeyAdapter{



public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
     if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
 Builder.getInstance().plaatje.setText("UP");
         Builder.getInstance().plaatje.setLocation(Builder.getInstance().plaatje.getX(),      Builder.getInstance().plaatje.getY()-5);
         Builder.getInstance().plaatje.repaint();
        }
     else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) { 
     Builder.getInstance().plaatje.setText("DOWN");
         Builder.getInstance().plaatje.setLocation(Builder.getInstance().plaatje.getX(), Builder.getInstance().plaatje.getY()+5);
         Builder.getInstance().plaatje.repaint();
        }
     else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
   Builder.getInstance().plaatje.setText("LEFT");
         Builder.getInstance().plaatje.setLocation(Builder.getInstance().plaatje.getX()-5, Builder.getInstance().plaatje.getY());
         Builder.getInstance().plaatje.repaint();
        }
     else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
      Builder.getInstance().plaatje.setText("RIGHT");
         Builder.getInstance().plaatje.setLocation(Builder.getInstance().plaatje.getX()+5, Builder.getInstance().plaatje.getY());
         Builder.getInstance().plaatje.repaint();
        }

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {


}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {


} 
}
```

I hope someone can help.

Comment: You haven't posted code that highlights your problem

Comment: Now i did. i forgot, im sorry. The code that highlights my problem is Builder.getInstance().plaatje.setText("UP");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use an AbsoluteLayout. `setLayout(null)`
Changing label's text causes container valitdate(). That means container recalculate positions, and you are using a layout, so its reset.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Builder extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

public JLabel plaatje = new JLabel();
public static Builder instance;

public static Builder getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Builder();
    }
    return instance;
}

public Builder() {
    setSize(getMaximumSize());
    this.addKeyListener(this);
    setLayout(null);
    plaatje.setText("UP");

    add(plaatje);
    plaatje.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);

}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        Builder.getInstance().plaatje.setText("UP");
        Builder.getInstance().plaatje.setLocation(Builder.getInstance().plaatje.getX(), Builder.getInstance().plaatje.getY() - 5);
        Builder.getInstance().plaatje.repaint();
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        Builder.getInstance().plaatje.setText("DOWN");
        Builder.getInstance().plaatje.setLocation(Builder.getInstance().plaatje.getX(), Builder.getInstance().plaatje.getY() + 5);
        Builder.getInstance().plaatje.repaint();
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        Builder.getInstance().plaatje.setText("LEFT");
        Builder.getInstance().plaatje.setLocation(Builder.getInstance().plaatje.getX() - 5, Builder.getInstance().plaatje.getY());
        Builder.getInstance().plaatje.repaint();
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        Builder.getInstance().plaatje.setText("RIGHT");
        Builder.getInstance().plaatje.setLocation(Builder.getInstance().plaatje.getX() + 5, Builder.getInstance().plaatje.getY());
        Builder.getInstance().plaatje.repaint();
    }

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Builder.getInstance().setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that even though you are setting your layoutmanager to null on your frame, you've set it to a GroupLayout on your contentPane

`getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);`

When you're calling setLocation manually, this works because your contentpane is not revalidating. But when you call setText, it's calling validate().

So if you want moving components, my advice is to set the layout on your contentpane to null